# Windows Server 2008R2 - No Updates Installed on this Computer

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-patching

We use Ivanti to patch servers and all of a sudden one Server 2008 R2 machine will not install patches.  I went to the server to review patches installed and there are no patches under currently installed updates.

Message: No Updates are Installed on this Computer

I tried renaming Software Distribution folder and ran wuauclt /detectnow /resetauthorization but still have the issue.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was resolved by running sfc /scannow.